# FOR LOOP fails to iterate through the object vector where purchase transactions are stored

Tags: c++

I'm unsure why when more than one transaction has been made the FOR LOOP won't iterate through the vector of "buyers". Am I missing something simple? I've spent the last few hours trying to fix this but to no avail. If any one could possibly help with my problem I'd be eternally grateful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;
//This class is for the car details that the user can purchase.
class cCar {
private:
    string _sName;
    double _dPrice;

public:
    cCar(string s, double d)
    {
        _sName = s;
        _dPrice = d;
    }
    string getName() { return _sName; }
    double getPrice() { return _dPrice; }
};
//This is where all the car detail purchases are created and stored in the object 'carlist'
vector<cCar> CarDatabase(vector<cCar>& car_list)
{
    car_list.push_back(cCar("Blue Nissan Skyline", 1000));
    car_list.push_back(cCar("Red Mini", 3000));
    car_list.push_back(cCar("Black Land Rover", 4000));
    car_list.push_back(cCar("Beatle", 9000));
    car_list.push_back(cCar("Ferrari", 300000));
    return car_list;
}
//This class stores the user's transactions
class Finance {
private:
    string _sUserName;
    double _dCostOfCar;
    string _sChosenCar;
    int _iFinancePlan;
    double _dDepositedAmount;
    double _dMonthlyPayments;
    double _dTotalLeftToPay;

public:
    Finance(string sName, double dCostOfCar, string sChosenCar, int iFinancePlan, double dDepositedAmount, double dDMonthlyPayments, double dTotalLeftToPay)
    {
        _sUserName = sName;
        _dCostOfCar = dCostOfCar;
        _sChosenCar = sChosenCar;
        _iFinancePlan = iFinancePlan;
        _dDepositedAmount = dDepositedAmount;
        _dMonthlyPayments = dDMonthlyPayments;
        _dTotalLeftToPay = dTotalLeftToPay;
    }
    string getUserName() { return _sUserName; }
    double getdCostOfCar() { return _dCostOfCar; }
    string getChosenCar() { return _sChosenCar; }
    int getFinancePlan() { return _iFinancePlan; }
    double getDepositAmount() { return _dDepositedAmount; }
    double getMonthlyAmount() { return _dMonthlyPayments; }
    double getTotalLeftToPay() { return _dTotalLeftToPay; }
};

//1. This displays the car menu items.
void display_menu(vector<cCar>& car_list)
{
    cout << "\nMENU";
    for (int iCount = 0; iCount != car_list.size(); iCount++) {
        cout << "\n" << iCount + 1 << ". " << car_list[iCount].getName();
        cout << "\n\tPrice: £" << car_list[iCount].getPrice();
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

//This procedure proccesses the user's selection and all information regarding price and name of car are then transferred to transaction variables.
void selectedCar(vector<cCar>& car_list, string& sNameOfChosenCar, double& dCostOfChosenCar)
{

    int iSelectionFromMenu = -1;

    do {
        cout << "\nChoose a car that you'd wish to buy from the menu (1 - " << car_list.size() << "): ";
        cin >> iSelectionFromMenu;
        if (iSelectionFromMenu > 0 && iSelectionFromMenu <= car_list.size()) {
            sNameOfChosenCar = car_list[iSelectionFromMenu - 1].getName();
            dCostOfChosenCar = car_list[iSelectionFromMenu - 1].getPrice();
        }
        else {
            cout << "\nPlease enter valid number!";
            iSelectionFromMenu = -1;
        }
    } while (iSelectionFromMenu == -1);
}
//This procedure gets from the user their preferred finance plan through their input.
void FinanceLength(int& iFinanceLength)
{
    do {
        cout << "\nHow long do you wish for your finance plan to last? (1 - 4 years): ";
        cin >> iFinanceLength;
        if (iFinanceLength < 0 || iFinanceLength > 4) {
            cout << "\nOops, try again! Please enter between 1 - 4!";
        }
    } while (iFinanceLength < 0 || iFinanceLength > 4);
}

//This procedure gets the user's deposit.
void DepositMoney(double& dDepositAmount)
{
    do {
        cout << "\nEnter deposit amount (minimum £500 accepted): £";
        cin >> dDepositAmount;
        if (dDepositAmount < 500) {
            cout << "\nTry again! Deposit an amount greater than or equal to £500.";
        }
    } while (dDepositAmount < 500);
}

//This function calculates the amount of money the user has to pay after deposit, added tax and charge percentage of 10%
double TotalLeftToPay(double iFinanceLength, double dDepositAmount, double dCostOfChosenCar)
{
    double dChargePercentage = 0.10;
    double dTotalLeftToPay = dCostOfChosenCar + (dCostOfChosenCar * dChargePercentage) - dDepositAmount + 135;
    return dTotalLeftToPay;
}

//This calculates monthly payments.
double MonthlyPayments(double dTotalLeftToPay, int iFinanceLength)
{
    double dMonthlyPayments = (dTotalLeftToPay / iFinanceLength) / 12;
    return dMonthlyPayments;
}
//This asks the user whether they'd like to restart the application.
void RestartOptions(char& cOption, bool& bExit)
{
    do {
        cout << "\nDo you wish to make another purchase? (y/n): ";
        cin >> cOption;
        cOption = toupper(cOption);
        switch (cOption) {
        case 'Y':
            bExit = false;
            break;
        case 'N':
            bExit = true;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Sorry, that's an invalid input, please try again!";
            continue;
        }
    } while (cOption != 'y' && cOption != 'Y' && cOption != 'n' && cOption != 'N');
}

//This string function returns either year or years (plural)
string YearOrYears(int iFinanceLength)
{
    return (iFinanceLength > 1) ? "years" : "year";
}

//This displays receipt of the user's transaction.
//HERE IS WHRERE I "M STRUGGLING TO ITERATE
void Receipt(const string& sUserName, const int& iFinanceLength, const double& dDepositAmount, char cOption, bool& bExit, const string& sNameOfChosenCar, const double& dCostOfChosenCar, vector<Finance>& buyers)
{
    double dTotalLeftToPay = TotalLeftToPay(iFinanceLength, dDepositAmount, dCostOfChosenCar);
    double dMonthlyPayments = MonthlyPayments(dTotalLeftToPay, iFinanceLength);
    buyers.push_back(Finance(sUserName, dCostOfChosenCar, sNameOfChosenCar, iFinanceLength, dDepositAmount, dMonthlyPayments, dTotalLeftToPay));
    for (int iCount = 0; iCount != buyers.size(); iCount++) {
        cout << "\nReceipt for: " << buyers[iCount].getUserName() << ". ";
        cout << "\nYou have chosen " << buyers[iCount].getChosenCar() << ".";
        cout << "\nYour finance plan timescale is " << buyers[iCount].getFinancePlan() << " " << YearOrYears(iFinanceLength) << ".";
        cout << "\nYou've deposited £" << buyers[iCount].getDepositAmount() << ".";
        cout << "\nTotal left to pay: £" << buyers[iCount].getTotalLeftToPay();
        cout << "\nMonthly Payments: £" << buyers[iCount].getMonthlyAmount();
        cout << "\n";
    }

    RestartOptions(cOption, bExit);
}

//This asks the user whether they're happy with the options of they've chosen.
void AcceptDeclineOptions(string& sUserName, int& iFinanceLength, double& dDepositAmount, bool& bExit, string& sNameOfChosenCar, double& dCostOfChosenCar, vector<Finance> buyers)
{
    char cOption = 0;
    do {
        cout << "\nConfirm finance plan (y/n): ";
        cin >> cOption;
        cOption = toupper(cOption);
        if (cOption == 'Y' || cOption == 'N') {
            if (cOption == 'Y') {
                Receipt(sUserName, iFinanceLength, dDepositAmount, cOption, bExit, sNameOfChosenCar, dCostOfChosenCar, buyers);
            }
            else {
                RestartOptions(cOption, bExit);
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "\nSorry, that's not a valid command.";
        }
    } while (cOption != 'Y' && cOption != 'N');
}

int main()
{
    bool bExit = false;
    int iFinanceLength = 0;
    double dDepositAmount = 0;
    string sNameOfChosenCar = "";
    double dCostOfChosenCar = 0;
    vector<cCar> car_list;
    CarDatabase(car_list);
    vector<cCar> car_purchases;
    vector<Finance> buyers;
    do {
        cout << "Welcome!";
        string sUserName = "";
        cout << "\nEnter your name: ";
        cin >> sUserName;
        display_menu(car_list);
        selectedCar(car_list, sNameOfChosenCar, dCostOfChosenCar);
        FinanceLength(iFinanceLength);
        DepositMoney(dDepositAmount);
        AcceptDeclineOptions(sUserName, iFinanceLength, dDepositAmount, bExit, sNameOfChosenCar, dCostOfChosenCar, buyers);
    } while (bExit == false);
}
```

Comment: Maybe `buyers` is empty.

Comment: Not when I've tested it, I did 4 transactions and it just keeps updating it to the new one I just did. It doesn't seem to store the transaction.

Comment: `AcceptDeclineOptions()` passes `buyers` by value. Meaning makes a copy. It won't affect `buyers` in `main()`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I can't believe I missed something that simple. I'm eternally grateful!